# Remove Duplicates from Two Dimensional ArrayList

Tags: java

I have a two dimensional ArrayList that I need to filter the duplicates out of.

current result of generateRows: [["one"], ["two"], ["three"], ["one"]]

***Java Pseudo Code:***

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
rows = generateRows(); //method not shown, but returns a ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (ArrayList<String> list:rows) {
    set.addAll (list);
}
rows.clear();
rows.add(new ArrayList<String>(set));
```

current result after running above conversion code: [[one, two, three]]

desired result: [["one"], ["two"], ["three"]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping code in same lines as what you have posted, here is what you have to do.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
rows = generateRows(); //method not shown, but returns a ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
Set<ArrayList<String>> set = new LinkedHashSet<ArrayList<String>>();
set.addAll(rows);
rows.clear();
rows.addAll(set);
```

Main issue with your routine:

`Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();` you are saying set is going to contain String types while your real set of objects to be unique is of ArrayList type

Answer (score 1):

You can't store `String` values (`"one"`, `"two"`, `"three"`) in a list which is supposed to store `ArrayList<String>` values.

To store the three strings, you'll need to create a new list of type `ArrayList<String>`.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
rows = generateRows();
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (ArrayList<String> list:rows) {
    set.addAll (list);
}

//rows.clear();
//rows.add(new ArrayList<String>(set));

ArrayList<String> noDups = new ArrayList<String>(set);
```

---

Btw,

- These lines...

  ```
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
  rows = generateRows();
  ```

  are equivalent to

  ```
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows = generateRows();
  ```
- You should prefer to program against interfaces instead of concrete classes, so if I were you I would write it as

  ```
  List<List<String>> rows = generateRows();
  ```